# Neo4J with OGM dynamic @RelationshipEntity/@Relationship value

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, relationship, neo4j-ogm

It´s possible to use a dynamic value for Relation Nodes?
I would like to set different Relation make for each graph on Neo4j, I think this could increase the performance of Neo4j, but I would like to know if it´s possible to use OGM on Java with dynamic value for the relations.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By "dynamic value for Relation Nodes" you mean dynamic relationship types, right? Remember that relationships are not nodes.

Comment: Sorry my english.
yes, I mean: The Relation Between nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create relationships with dynamic types you can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and use the procedure `apoc.create.relationship`. This procedure creates relationships with dynamic relationship type.

For example:

```
with "REL_TYPE" as reltype
match (n1:Node {id:1}), (n2:Node {id:2})
call apoc.create.relationship(n1, reltype,{}, n2) yield rel
return *
```

will create a relationship `-[:REL_TYPE]-` between `n1` and `n2`.

With this approach you can pass the relationship type string as parameter to Neo4j in your Java application, then call `apoc.create.relationship`.

Comment: But this implementation I will need to avoid to use of OGM, that´s correct?
Using OGM this dynamic relation type will not be possible, correct?
I check all documentation and I don´t found anything.

Do you already use the relation dynamic type? This make the Neo4J be faster for large Graphs?

Comment: @Dante No, you don't need to avoid the use of OGM. APOC procedures is a library of procedures for Neo4j database. There is no relation with your Java or OGM code. Why are you trying to create dynamic relationship types? What are your use case?

Comment: In our scenario we have more then one graph in the same Neo4J instance, where each graph has on root Node and unlimited children´s, who can have more children´s and so on.
So we made a mapping using recursion where I have the Node pointing to the Edge and the Edge pointing to the Node.
In this scenario all edges has the same type, but for each graph I would like the define a unique type, to optimize the cypher queries. (I really not sure if this approache will bring optimization)

Comment: @Dante Let us continue this discussion [on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164843/room-for-bruno-peres-and-dante).

Comment: Well that´s possible to, but we discuss on chat I think I could not improve my queries using this approach.

Thanks for help.